# Converting a list of Datetime values into a list of Timestamp values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to append to a list of Timestamp values with another list derived as Datetime string values.

eg here is an example of my Timestamp list:

```
Tlist = [Timestamp('2021-09-20 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-09-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-09-22 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-09-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-09-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-09-27 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-09-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-09-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-09-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00')]
```

Here is an example of my Datetime list:

```
Dlist = ['2021-10-04', '2021-10-05', '2021-10-06', '2021-10-07', '2021-10-08']
```

Whilst I can see how to take an individual Datetime string value, convert it to Timestamp and add it to the Tlist I can not seem to find any combinations of functions that will allow me to operate on this systematically as a list. Appreciate any help, Thanks

Comment: is this Python? if so, are you working with pandas? that's important because you'd tread a pd.Series differently than a Python list (different methods etc.).

Comment: Yes this is Python and am "trying" to use and understand Panas; Ultimately I am trying to get a vector that I will ultimately use as the x axis of a matplot plt; I have extended the range of my Y values and am now trying to extend the date range to match.

Comment: ok I've set the appropriate tags; that will help others find your question. pandas offers nice timeseries support, [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) are a good starting point

Comment: Thanks @MrFuppes, I got there in the end; the bit I was missing was getting my head around use of the DatetimeIndex function it took me a while; probably a function of my poor Python skills, this said the end point is still rather convoluted. If other are following I found this page helpful in leading me through what was needed:  https://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-time-series-examples-datetimeindex-periodindex-and-timedeltaindex